# Using a node.js website for a front-end java/c#/html application

Tags: node.js, server, frontend, backend, web-frontend

I'm having a front-end and a back-end for a website in node.js using Express.

Now I want to add another front-end who is in Java. I want to have an app where I can fill a form and add a user. On the btn_create_user_pressed, I want to call my server in node.js and create it with feedback like: User created-User already exist-etc.

I thought I could call localhost:3000/adduser with a POST but in my routes, It redirect if creation was successful

How to modify my routes and/or my view so the redirection will not be dependent of my addUser operations and so i'll be able to call it from any other front-end side.

Here's my newuser.jade

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    form#formAddUser(name="adduser",mehod="post",action="/adduser")
        input#inputUserName(type="text", placeholder="Votre Nom", name="username")
        input#inputUserEmail(type="text", placeholder="Votre Email", name="useremail")
        button#btnSubmit(type="submit") Envoyer
```

It call my route adduser:

```
/* POST to Add User Service */
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {

    // Set our internal DB variable
    var db = req.db;

    // Get our form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
    var userName = req.body.username;
    var userEmail = req.body.useremail;

    // Set our collection
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');

    // Submit to the DB
    collection.insert({
        "username" : userName,
        "email" : userEmail
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            // If it failed, return error
            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        }
        else {
            // And forward to success page
            res.redirect("userlist");
        }
    });
});
```